# override uploaded file class

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('file', 'file', array(
            'required' => true,
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Document\File\ImageFile'
        ))
.......

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Document\User',
        'csrf_protection'   => false
    ));
}
```

- is it possible to change (map?) the class from UploadedFile to my own class ImageFile?

Regards, Marek

Comment: I see that there is sth called modelTransformer - will it be good?

Comment: take a look at this [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)